# How to force an HTML page to have a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, width

I'm making a game with HTML canvas and javascript. At the moment, javascript in my head generates the complicated canvas element. In the body is only a small p with instructions. The game is about 1100px x 600 px. If you go to the page with a smaller resolution screen, the remainder of the game is clipped off the edge. I want the page to have a browser-native horizontal and vertical scrollbar they can use to scroll the game.

I've looked at various combinations of containers and min-width but I was wondering if there's a standard practice for this?

Comment: will `overflow-x: scroll;` work?

Comment: Scroll occurs by default unless you disable it. You'll need to figure out what's doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS overflow property, specifies whether to clip content, **render scrollbars**, or just display content when it overflows its block level container.

Try adding the ID `#scrollable` to the element you want to force a scrollbar on and then

```
#scrollable{
    overflow: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

If you want to force overflow scroll in a single axis, you can use:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

or

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

[MDN Docs on overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y` and CSS

```
body {
   overflow-x: scroll; /*For regular vertical scroll */
   overflow-y: scroll; /*For Horizontal scroll */
}
```